# Why is Volume^2 at most product of the 3 projections?

Tags: integration, geometry, reference-request, inequality, volume

Is there a simple proof for
$$
  \text{Vol}^2(P)\le \prod_{i=x,y,z} \text{Area}(\text{Proj}_i(P)),
$$
where $P\subset \mathbb R^3$ and $\text{Proj}_z(P)$ denotes the projection of $P$ to the $z=0$ plane?

I have a complicated proof for this (in any dimension) using shifts but I wonder if this inequality is something well-known/simple.

Comment: The problem has been posed here [previously](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/157721/856), but since this question is specifically asking for a *simple* proof, I would not vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, following your link I've reached http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loomis%E2%80%93Whitney_inequality which is just what I was looking for as their proof is pretty simple: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5.pdf

Comment: also refer to [this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188009)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have learned from Gabor Tardos (and Peter Csikvari) this is well-known and can be proved easily using the submodularity of entropy. First we reduce the problem to the finite case by approximating $P$ by a collection of cubes. Then let us select a cube uniformly random and denote its $i$-th coordinate by $X_i$. We have
$$\log Vol^2(P)=H(X_1,X_2,X_3)+H(X_1,X_2,X_3)\le H(X_1,X_2)+H(X_1,X_3)-H(X_1)+H(X_1,X_2,X_3)\le H(X_1,X_2)+H(X_1,X_3)+H(X_2,X_3)\le \Pi_{i=x,y,z} Area(Proj_i(P)).$$

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case of the [Loomis-Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loomis%E2%80%93Whitney_inequality) inequality.  First, some biographical information:

---

- [Lynn Harold Loomis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynn_Harold_Loomis) was an analyst.  He got his PhD under Salomon Bochner at Harvard in 1942.  Later he would teach at the same school.  He co-aurthored *[Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/)* with Shlomo Sternberg.
- [Hassler Whitney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hassler_Whitney) was a reknown topologist.  He came from a rather learned family in New York City, studied at Yale where he got degrees in Physics and Music.

---

The Loomis Inequality appears in [An Inequality Related to the Isoperimetric Inequality](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5/S0002-9904-1949-09320-5.pdf).  The result states:

> Let $m$ be the measure of an open subset of Euclidean $n$-space, $O \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $m_1, \dots, m_n$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional measures of the projections on the coordinate hyperplanes. Then $m^{n-1} \leq m_1\dots m_n$

We can take $n=3$.  The Loomis-Whitney paper is 2 pages long and we will summarize it here:

- **Step 1** Reduce to a counting problem:

  > Let $S$ be a set of cubes from the cubical subdivision of $n$-space and let $S_i$ be the set of $n$-cubes by projecting the cubes of $S$ onto the $i$th coordinate hyperplane.  Let $N$ be the number of cubes in $S$ and $N_i$ be the number of cubes in $N_i$ then $N^{n-1} \leq N_1 \dots N_n$
- This cubic apprxoximation works since the number of cubes is a good approximation to the volume or "measure" of the set $S$.  We just set the cubes of size $\delta$ and count.
- **Step 2** How do we prove the above lemma? The proof is by induction on the number of dimensions:

  - The cubes project into intervals $I_1, \dots, I_k$ if we project to the first axis.  Here $k$ might be very large set of intervals.
  - For each interval $I_i$, let $T_i$ be the set of cubes projecting into $T_i$.  Let $T_{i \to j}$ be the projection of $T_i$ onto the $j$-th hyperplane.
  - Let $a_i$ be the number of cubes in $T_i$. We can count the cubes so that 
    $$ \begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = N \\
    \sum_{i=1}^k a_{i \to j} = N_j \end{align}$$
    and by induction hypothesis $a_i^{n-2} \leq a_{i \to 2} \dots a_{i \to n}$ which implies $a_i^{n-1} \leq N_i a_{i \to 2} \dots a_{i \to n}$
  - The last step follows from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) ...

Comment: Interesting. I suspect that Step 2 could work with Combinatorical Nullstelenstaz.

Comment: Here is a proof in the notes of Guth on the [Polynomial Method](http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect29b.pdf) the cube $\square$ seems to be a natural shape for this type of projection inequality.  Notes by [Noga Alon](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/null2.pdf) on combinatorial nullstellensatz seem similar in spirit, though I do like the geometric flavor of the original result.